# Cannot declare a static variable in the kernel program OpenCL

Tags: function, static, opencl, mql5

Here is the code of the kernel:

```
"__kernel void CalculateLWMA(                                           \r\n"
                            "int rates_total,                                 \r\n"
                            "int prev_calculated,                             \r\n"
                            "int begin,                                       \r\n"
                            "int InpMAPeriod,                                 \r\n"
                            "__global double *price,                          \r\n"
                            "__global double *ExtLineBuffer                   \r\n"
                            ")                                                 \r\n"
        "{                                                              \r\n"
            "int        i,limit;                                           \r\n"
            "static int weightsum;                                                \r\n"
            "double     sum;                                               \r\n"
            "if(prev_calculated==0)                                        \r\n"
            "{                                                             \r\n"                                   
            "weightsum=0;                                                  \r\n"
            "limit=InpMAPeriod+begin;                                      \r\n"
            "for(i=0;i<limit;i++) ExtLineBuffer[i]=0.0;                    \r\n"
            "double firstValue=0;                                          \r\n"
            "for(i=begin;i<limit;i++)                                      \r\n"
            "{                                                             \r\n"
                "int k=i-begin+1;                                          \r\n"
                "weightsum+=k;                                             \r\n"
                "firstValue+=k*price[i];                                   \r\n"
            "}                                                             \r\n"
            "firstValue/=(double)weightsum;                                \r\n"
            "ExtLineBuffer[limit-1]=firstValue;                            \r\n"
            "}                                                             \r\n"
            "else limit=prev_calculated-1;                                 \r\n"
            "for(i=limit;i<rates_total;i++)                                \r\n"
            "{                                                             \r\n"
            "sum=0;                                                        \r\n"
            "for(int j=0;j<InpMAPeriod;j++) sum+=(InpMAPeriod-j)*price[i-j];\r\n"
            "ExtLineBuffer[i]=sum/weightsum;                               \r\n"
            "}                                                             \r\n"
        "}
```

As one can see the line: `"static int weightsum; \r\n"` i s giving the following error:

```
error: variables in function scope cannot be declared static
```

Kindly, let me know what can be the replacement for the `static` in OpenCL kernel program function?

Comment: Have you tried declaring it as a global before the kernel function?

Comment: Well I didn't.. Let me try it out.

Comment: @pmdj Can you please tell me how I can declare global.... I tried `global int weightsum;`. Even `__global int weightsum,`. Didn't worked :(

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a better look at your code and noticed that your use of the static variable would be incorrect anyway, as `weightsum+=k` is not atomic or synchronised, and even if you had barriers, there would be concurrent reads & writes from different work items. You can't do that in OpenCL. Global variables need to be constant.

The other thing is that you've not got any calls to `get_global_id(0)` or similar, which is a big red flag - all your work items will be running the exact same code as each other, or you've only got one work item. The former means you're throwing away computation results on a massive scale, the latter means you're not actually using any parallelism. In both cases, your code will be slow. It does mean that `weightsum` actually doesn't need to be static.

If you want mutable global memory, you have to pass it in as a buffer. Note that if multiple work items need to write to the same memory word in that buffer (or if one writes and others read), you will need to use global barriers or atomics. A better way would be to use reductions - searching for e.g. "OpenCL parallel sum reduction" should get you somewhere. Essentially, each work-item will do as much work as it can in isolation, and then the work-items will cooperate to hierarchically combine their results. This typically has a complexity of O(log(N)) rather than the O(N) of naive use of atomics.

Comment: This is insights answer .. I appreciate your time and the valueable advise. I am a bit new to OpenCL. Hence, trying to understand how it works parallel. I tried to have worker set for that but I guess they are of no use. Can help me modify the above code as per multi work item so my code run faster? Help me optimized it.